# What term describes the production of new words by 'aggregating them'?

Tags: terminology, morphology, word-formation

Certain words seem to come from gluing or aggregating other extant words; what is the technical name given for phenomenon?

For example:

In Sanskrit: *pratyaksanamanagamah*; where *pratyaksa* is percept, *anumana* is inference, and *agamah* is testimony

In English:
*Being-in-the-World*, where the words are hyphenated

In German: 
*SchifffartskanalaufsichtsbevollmachtIfer*; where *schifft* is ship, *fahrt* sailing, *Kanal* is canal, *aufsicht* is supervising, and *bevollmachtiger* is supervise.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as [*compounding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_%28linguistics%29).

I might add that compounds are not usually made up of full-inflected words with case and number, they are generally based on the stems that get inflection. Hence *pratyakṣa* in that compound does not have a case marker, as self-standing words of Sanskrit do.